# Memory leak on reading images from document directory

Tags: iphone

I am reading images from document directory in a loop.

```
for(iArrCount=0;iArrCount<[arrImages count];iArrCount++)
    {
UIButton *btnImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(xRow, yRow, width, height);
            [btnImage addTarget:self action:@selector(imageDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            btnImage.tag = iCount;
            if(iCount<[arrImages count])
            {


                NSString *workSpacePath=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[arrImages objectAtIndex:iCount]];
                [btnImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [scrollImages addSubview:btnImage];
}
}
```

On doing so, control goes to `didRecieveMemoryWarning` and application crashes. If I replace the image by a image from resource folder, application does not crashes. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your buttons are maintaining a reference to the full resolution image. What you will need to do is scale down the image to your button dimensions and set that scaled down image as your button background. Something like this should do the trick:

Create a category on UIImage... Let's call it UIImage+Scaler.h

```
// UIImage+Scaler.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Scaler)
- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
// UIImage+Scaler.m
#import "UIImage+Scaler.h"

#define kBitsPerComponent 8
#define kBitmapInfo       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast

- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kBitmapInfo;
    size_t bytesPerRow = size.width * 4.0;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, size.width, 
                                   size.height, kBitsPerComponent, 
                                   bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);

    CGImageRef scaledImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scaledImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(scaledImageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return scaledImage;
}
```

OK, now back to your code. Like the other posters said you'll need an autorelease pool.

```
CGSize buttonSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

for(iArrCount=0;iArrCount<[arrImages count];iArrCount++)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIButton *btnImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(xRow, yRow, width, height);
    [btnImage addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(imageDetails:)      
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnImage.tag = iCount;
    if(iCount<[arrImages count])
    {
        NSString *workSpacePath=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]  
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                            [arrImages objectAtIndex:iCount]];
        UIImage* bigImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData   
                             dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];
        UIImage* smallImage = [bigImage scaleToSize:buttonSize];
        [btnImage setBackgroundImage:smallImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [scrollImages addSubview:btnImage];
    }
    [pool drain]; // must drain pool inside loop to release bigImage
}
```

Hope this solves for problem.

Comment: You could also utilize a dispatch_apply instead of the for loop and get all of that work off the main queue.  Then when add the button to the scroll view dispatch that method via the main queue.  Tis way we won't block the main thread while loading the images.

Comment: @timthetoolman Great suggestion! You could also cache the scaled down images (persistently) and only calculate them for new images... But since the OP is struggling with some basic memory management issues probably best not to complicate matters too much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `for` loop in an autorelease pool:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
for(...)
{
   ....
}
[pool release];
```

Comment: Still crashing. I found one thing. I commented out line [btn setBackgroundImage] and assigned a resource image. But I didn't comment out the line of reading file from document directory. App didn't crash.

Comment: Check what happening in `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSAutoreleasePool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsautoreleasepool_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Keep your code inside an autoreleasepool.

```
for(iArrCount=0;iArrCount<[arrImages count];iArrCount++)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    ......
    ......
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Still crashing. I found one thing. I commented out line [btn setBackgroundImage] and assigned a resource image. But I didn't comment out the line of reading file from document directory. App didn't crash.

Comment: Hmm, It seems the images are large and hence it requires huge memory. Thats why its crashing. I think you should go for re-using the button, something like we are re-using the tablecell.